# Find data by multiple variable names in R

Tags: r

I have a question regarding variables names in R.

In my dataset I have a list of 70 variable names as characters and I want to find the corresponding data (including the header) in the data.

For example I used the dataset iris. I don't want to select all variables by iris$Sepal.Length since I have 70 variables in the dataset that I use. In my code I can print the data but I am struggling with saving the data as a dataframe with the corresponding header names. Somebody any thoughts?

```
iris
head(iris)
colnames(iris)
b <- list("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")

i=1
for (i in 1:length(b)){
#print(b[[i]])
print(iris[,c(b[[i]])])
c[,i]<-(iris[,c(b[[i]])])
}
```

Comment: If you want to select certain columns, define b as a vector `b=c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")`, and then do `iris[,b]`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  get certain columns from a data frame?

Comment: A `list` is a great data structure because it lets you use variables of different types - you can have a matrix, then a data frame, then a model, all in the same list. When all your data is the same type, just use a vector: `c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")`

Comment: Yes, I have a list of variable names in my own data and want to make a data.frame which would contain these variables with the corresponding data. I think Lamia's code is actually already working and I am looking into the dplyr as well. Many thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get a subset of 70 columns from a data.frame or matrix.  The 70 columns you have are stored in a `list`.  R will let you get columns named by a `character` vector, but not by a `list`.  So, you can just use `unlist`.

```
b <- list("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")
newTable <- iris[,unlist(b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I find dplyr the best for this. If you turn iris into a tibble

```
iris <- as_tibble(iris)
```

You can then use the dplyr::select function either selecting by name (no quotes) or by position. You can even use the 1:5 notation selecting columns 1 to 5. A great place to start is: http://r4ds.had.co.nz

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?

```
b <- c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")
New_iris=iris[,b]
```